# Using fields from a 'lookup-ed' sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have two Sharepoint lists:
- Assignments
  - Activities

The activities list has a lookup field to the assignments list as activities (e.g. monthly review of X) are related to an assignment.

My question is, how would I display other fields from Assignments in a view of Activities using standard Sharepoint 2007 (we have restrictions on using SP Designer or Visual Studio as it is a 'standard' corporate environment)?

E.x.

**Assignments**

```
Assignment    Frequency    Area       Assigned To 
Read X        Monthly      Finance    Bill
```

**Activities**

```
Assignment    Date        Action
Read X        2-Mar-08    No actions needed
Read X        3-Apr-08    Adjust Y
```

**Desired SharePoint List (to view/sort/filter)**

```
Assignment    Frequency    Area       Assigned To    Date        Action
Read X        Monthly      Finance    Bill           2-Mar-08    No actions needed
Read X        Monthly      Finance    Bill           3-Apr-08    Adjust Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use the Data View Web Part from SPD, then I think you are going to have to use a content editor webpart and do this all in javascript. [intro article](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/02/28/more-sharepoint-branding-customisation-using-javascript-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a workaround that doesn't use Sharepoint designer but it's a bit of a hack.  In MS Access, I linked two tables to each of my Sharepoint lists and created a query which linked them together.  I then created an Excel file and put it on the Sharepoint that references the MS Access file (the Excel file has a hyperlink to the edit field).